# Get one row per unique field value SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have found several answers to this question elsewhere, however have been unable to really apply those answers to my particular situation.

Lets take the following table:

```
ID |   Name   |    Item    | Year
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
1  | Dan      | Chlorine   | 2014
2  | Dan      | Oxygen     | 2013
3  | Jon      | Helium     | 2014
4  | Jon      | Aluminum   | 2015
5  | Dan      | Propane    | 2014
6  | Dan      | Chlorine   | 2016
```

What I am looking for is a query that returns all of Dan's records, but I only want to return the latest record (by year) if there is a duplicate item (no possibility for a tie).

So for the above table, I want the following returned:

```
ID |   Name   |    Item    | Year
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
2  | Dan      | Oxygen     | 2013
5  | Dan      | Propane    | 2014
6  | Dan      | Chlorine   | 2016
```

Currently I have the following query which will simply get ALL of Dan's items sorted by year:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Name` = `Dan` ORDER BY `Year` DESC;
```

How do I take this the step further to only get one row per year per Item?

Comment: There are thousands of answers here (and elsewhere) that apply to your exact situation.

Comment: select * from t1 where (name, item, year) in (select name, item, max(year) from t1 where name = 'Dan' group by name, item). If you have duplicates for an item and year and name use distinct. I am ignoring optimization.

Comment: @Strawberry If latest will always correlate to a larger id then the query can be simplified and would mostly likely be more efficient assuming "id" is a key.  I would be conservative though [unless OP clarifies] because sometimes data corrections are done in databases and then such correlations no longer hold.

Comment: ID is a key and yes at this point larger ID's would be newer, however I'd rather use the year field.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table;

CREATE TABLE tmp_table as
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1=0;

ALTER TABLE tmp_table
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX UK_tmp_table (Name, Item);

INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_table(ID, Name, Item, Year)
SELECT ID, Name, Item, YEAR FROM `table` WHERE Name = 'Dan' ORDER BY `Year` DESC;

SELECT * FROM tmp_table ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: How does this eliminate record 1 from the original table since there is a later record which should take precedence (newer year).

Comment: replace "ORDER BY `Year` DESC" to "ORDER BY ID DESC"  ... in general

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *
                FROM `table`
                WHERE `Name` = 'Dan'
                ORDER BY `year` DESC
               ) as t1
          GROUP BY `Name` DESC;
```